# freezing time in a capybara integration test

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, timecop

I'm writing an integration test using capybara and capybara-webkit where I need to compare two times and it randomly fails because sometimes the second passes and I have failures like

```
expected: "Sep 01 2015 @ 04:49:17 employee_1"
     got: "Sep 01 2015 @ 04:49:18 employee_1"
```

In the non-integration test where I have to deal with time I use `Timecop.freeze` but if I try here I get

> Capybara::FrozenInTime:
>
> time appears to be frozen, Capybara does not work with libraries which freeze time, consider using time travelling instead

However, from my understanding time traveling doesn't fix my issue since the difference between times is always 1 sec.

Is there a way I can ensure the time does not change during test execution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to Capybara 2.5 and are using Ruby 2.0+ then Timecop.freeze should be usable. This is because Capybara 2.5 will now use the system monotonic clock for its waiting behavior if it is available, allowing for freezing of the ruby time methods.

Comment: Unfortunately Capybara 2.5 brakes some test I have and I do not have time to deal with that so I have manually frozen the time on my spec helper

Comment: What version Capybara are you running?  2.4.x to 2.5 shouldn't break anything.